# How to update multiple rows and database with same value at once? Laravel

Tags: php, forms, sql-update, laravel, laravel-3

I'm stuck in code. I managed to create a form that adds a multiple number of rows in db but I do not know how to update them at the same time when i need to use product_code as id.

This is table 1 (products) structure:

```
id | product_name | product_code
1  | Name1        | 101
2  | Name2        | 102
3  | Name3        | 103
4  | Name4        | 104
```

This is table 2 (products_ing) structure:

> ```
> id | product_code | ing_name  | ing_weight
> 1  | 101          | INGName1  | 110
> 2  | 101          | INGName2  | 10
> 3  | 101          | INGName3  | 54
> 4  | 101          | INGName4  | 248
> ```

This is edit function:

```
    public function post_edit($id = null)
{

    if(Input::get('submit'))
    {
        // ID
        if($id !== null)
        {
            $id = trim(filter_var($id, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
        }


        $input = Input::all();

        $validation = Validator::make($input);

        else
        {
            foreach ($input as $key => $value)
            {
                $input[$key] = ($value !== '') ? trim(filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) : null;
            }

            try
            {

                DB::table('products')
                    ->whereIn($id)
                    ->update(array(
            'product_name'          => $items['product_name'],
            'product_code'          => $items['product_code']
                ));


            }

    }

    return $this->get_edit($id);
}
```

With this I can only edit *product_name* and **product_code** from **products** table by id.
But I'm trying to update multiple rows from db with same **product_code** that would serve as id.

// I found on **Google images** one good image that explains what I'm trying to do but with Laravel:

[IMAGE LINK](http://s21.postimg.org/wlhw961dj/phpvisual.gif)

Is there a solution? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL: Let the database's `foreign key` do this for you, with the [ON UPDATE CASCADE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) command. This will update all referenced tables if you change the `product_code` in your base `products` table.

CREATE-Script of `products_ing`

```
...
product_code INT NOT NULL REFERENCES products(product_code) ON UPDATE CASCADE
...
```

As laravel `migration`

```
Schema::create('products_ing', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->int('product_code');
    $table->string('ing_name');
    $table->int('ing_weight');

    /* All the other key stuff */
    $table
        ->foreign('product_code')
        ->references('product_code')
        ->on('products')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
});
```

Comment: I apologize for the waiting. Thank you for this. This is great but is not all that I need. Just as you say _"This will update all referenced tables if you change the product_code in your base products table."_ I'm not well formulate question, and I apologize for that. I updated the question with more details. I'm trying to change multiple rows from db with same **product_code** that would serve as id, now I know only to edit one column with one id...